# How to change the value of the diagonal column of the matrix?

Tags: matlab

How do I change the list of value to all `1`? I need the top right to bottom left also end up with `1`.

```
rc = input('Please enter a value for rc: ');
mat = ones(rc,rc);
for i = 1:rc
    for j = 1:rc
        mat(i,j) = (i-1)+(j-1);
    end
end
final = mat
final(diag(final)) = 1 % this won't work?
```

Comment: can u kindly explain the code? what is 1:size and why do we +1:end?

Comment: sorry i need the top right to bottom left also end up with 1

Comment: ahh.. i see thanks for the explaination

Comment: Your original problem appeared to me as a duplicate case, but I guess your new question isn't, which I have posted as an edit to an answer that includes both cases, as also because comments don't stay here for long.

Comment: Also I think you should add this new question as an edit to your question.

Comment: @raryeng I think your edit changed the intent of the question. My understanding was the OP wanted all the elements along the main diagonal to be made into 1's, and also for the top right and bottom left entries to be made into 1's.

Comment: @David - oops. you are right.  Let me roll back.

Answer (score 1):

Code for the original problem -

```
final(1:size(final,1)+1:end)=1
```

Explanation: As an example consider a `5x5` final matrix, the diagonal elements would have indices as `(1,1)`, `(2,2)` .. `(5,5)`. Convert these to linear indices - `1`, `7` and so on till the very last element, which is exactly what `1:size(final,1)+1:end` gets us.

---

**Edit :** If you would like to set the diagonal(from top right to bottom left elements) as `1`, one approach would be -

```
final(fliplr(eye(size(final)))==1)=1
```

Explanation: In this case as well we can use linear indexing, but just for more readability and maybe a little fun, we can use logical indexing with a proper mask, which is being created with `fliplr(eye(size(final)))==1`.

But, if you care about performance, you can use linear indexing here as well, like this -

```
final(sub2ind(size(final),1:size(final,1),size(final,2):-1:1))=1
```

Explanation: Here we are creating the linear indices with the `rows` and `columns` indices of the elements to be set. The `rows` here would be - `1:size(final,1)` and `columns` are `size(final,2):-1:1`. We feed these two to `sub2ind` to get us the linear indices that we can use to index into `final` and set them to `1`.

If you would to squeeze out the max performance here, go with this raw version of `sub2ind` -

```
final([size(final,2)-1:-1:0]*size(final,1) + [1:size(final,1)])=1
```

Answer (score 1):

All of the approaches specified so far are great methods for doing what you're asking.

However, I'd like to provide another viewpoint and something that I've noticed in your code, as well as an interesting property of this matrix that may or may not have been noticed.  All of the anti-diagonal values in your matrix have values equal to `rc - 1`.

As such, if you want to set all of the anti-diagonal values to 1, you can cheat and simply find those values equal to `rc-1` and set these to `1`.  In other words:

```
final(final == rc-1) = 1;
```

---

## Minor note on efficiency

As a means of efficiency, you can do the same thing your two `for` loops are doing when constructing `mat` by using the [`hankel`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hankel.html) command:

```
mat = hankel(0:rc-1,rc-1:2*(rc-1))
```

How `hankel` works in this case is that the first row of the matrix is specified by the vector of `0:rc-1`.  After, each row that follows incrementally shifts values to the left and adds an increasing value of 1 to the right.  This keeps going until you encounter the vector seen in the second argument, and at this point we stop.  In other words, if we did:

```
mat = hankel(0:3,3:6)
```

This is what we get:

```
mat = 

 0     1     2     3
 1     2     3     4
 2     3     4     5
 3     4     5     6
```

Therefore, by specifying `rc = 5`, this is the matrix I get with `hankel`, which is identical to what your code produces (before setting the anti-diagonal to 1):

```
mat =

     0     1     2     3     4
     1     2     3     4     5
     2     3     4     5     6
     3     4     5     6     7
     4     5     6     7     8
```

---

## Tying it all together

With `hankel` and the cheat that I mentioned, we can compute what you are asking in three lines of code - with the first line of code asking for the dimensions of the matrix:

```
rc = input('Please enter a value for rc: ');
mat = hankel(0:rc-1, rc-1:2*(rc-1));
mat(mat == rc-1) = 1;
```

`mat` contains your final matrix.  Therefore, with `rc = 5`, this is the matrix I get:

```
mat =

     0     1     2     3     1
     1     2     3     1     5
     2     3     1     5     6
     3     1     5     6     7
     1     5     6     7     8
```

Comment: I used the fact that the top right/bottom left elements are `rc-1`, so I subtracted `rc-2` from them to get ones :P But nice spot on the hankel matrix!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it:

Say we have `a` the square matrix:

```
a = ones(5, 5)*5

a =

     5     5     5     5     5
     5     5     5     5     5
     5     5     5     5     5
     5     5     5     5     5
     5     5     5     5     5
```

You can remove the diagonal, then create a diagonal list of ones to replace it:

```
a = a - fliplr(diag(diag(fliplr(a)))) + fliplr(diag(ones(length(a), 1)))

a =

 5     5     5     5     1
 5     5     5     1     5
 5     5     1     5     5
 5     1     5     5     5
 1     5     5     5     5
```

The `diag(ones(length(a), 1))` can be any vector, ie. `1->5`:

```
 a = a - fliplr(diag(diag(fliplr(a)))) + fliplr(diag(1:length(a)))

 a =    
     5     5     5     5     1
     5     5     5     2     5
     5     5     3     5     5
     5     4     5     5     5
     5     5     5     5     5
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple method where I just add/subtract the appropriate matrices to end up with the right thing:

```
final=mat-diag(diag(mat-1))+fliplr(diag([2-rc zeros(1,rc-2) 2-rc]))
```